# Object of class stdClass could not be converted to int Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want check record from database in laravel 5.6 , but i get message 'Object of class stdClass could not be converted to int'.

```
  $pengoreksi = DB::table('peserta')->latest('pengoreksi')->first();

  if($pengoreksi <= 8){
    $korektor = $pengoreksi++;
  }
  else {
    $korektor = 1;
  }
```

Comment: `$pengoreksi` is not a __number__.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line you get db row with many columns, add column name

```
$pengoreksi = DB::table('peserta')->latest('pengoreksi')->first()->{**COLUMN_NAME**};
```

Answer (score 2):

According to docs,

If you just need to retrieve a single row from the database table, you may use the first method. This method will return a single StdClass object:

```
$user = DB::table('users')->where('name', 'John')->first();
echo $user->name;
```

You cannot use $pengoreksi directly, first store the value in any variable and then use it.

```
$pengoreksi = DB::table('peserta')->latest('pengoreksi')->first();
$pen = $pengoreksi->pengoreksi;
  if($pengoreksi <= 8){
    $korektor = $pen++;
  }
  else {
    $korektor = 1;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not working since you will retrieve an object. You need to access the value from the object to access your number.

```
$pengoreksi = DB::table('peserta')->latest('pengoreksi')->first();
//If you have saved pangoreksi as a string in your database you must type hint (int) on $pengoreksi->pangoreksi 
if($pengoreksi->pangoreksi <= 8){
    $korektor = $pengoreksi->pangoreksi++;
}
else {
    $korektor = 1;
}
```